# Why is self.whitecheckbox.stateChanged not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am coding a simple chatbot with GUI in python (the GUI is made with pyqt5 and qt designer) and I am currently working on the settings menu. When I change the background from white to black in the settings menu and click the save button, it does not change to black. I am very frustrated with this and would greatly appreciate if anyone would care to help.

Here is my code:

```
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
import requests
from random import randint as r
from datetime import datetime

class MyGUI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        global black
        global white
        global stngs
        stngs = 0
        super(MyGUI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("ChatbotUI.ui", self)
        self.show()

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pressenter)
        self.actionClose.triggered.connect(exit)
        self.actionSettings1.triggered.connect(self.gotosettings)
            
    def gotosettings(self):
        global stngs
        stngs = 1
        self.close()

        try:
            black
        except Exception:
            white = 1
            black = 0

        if black == 1:
            self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
            self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color : white;")
            self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
            self.menubar.setStyleSheet("color: white;")
            self.textBrowser.setTextColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
        elif white == 1:
            self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
            self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color : white;")
            self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.menubar.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
            self.textBrowser.setTextColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))

    def pressenter(self):
        userinput = self.lineEdit.text()
        response = self.get_response(userinput)
        self.textBrowser.setText(response)

    def get_response(self, userinput):
        global ait_ball_ans
        ait_ball_ans = [
            "Yes",
            "No",
            "Question unclear, ask later",
            "Maybe",
            "Obviously not",
            "Of course"
        ]

        #getting ip adress of user
        def get_ip():
            response = requests.get('https://api64.ipify.org?format=json').json()
            return response["ip"]

        #getting location info of user
        ip_address = get_ip()
        response = requests.get(f'https://ipapi.co/{ip_address}/json/').json()
            
        #weather api key and location info
        api_key = '14aaded169c4d6e2a5a2547d126b3f70'
        city = response.get("city") + ", " + response.get("country_code")
        qsi = userinput
        qs = qsi.lower().split()
        length = len(qs)

        if "what" in qs and ("name" in qs or "name?" in qs) and ("your" in qs or "ur" in qs) and (length == 3 or length == 4):
            print("My name is chatbot, and I am a language model trained by Zayan Arshad.")
            text = "My name is chatbot, and I am a language model trained by Zayan Arshad."
        elif ("chatbot" in qs or "chatbot?" in qs) and ("you" in qs and "are" in qs):
            print("Yes, my name is chatbot, a language model trained by Zayan Arshad.")
            text = "Yes, my name is chatbot, a language model trained by Zayan Arshad."
        elif "is" in qs and length == 4 and "chatbot" not in qs and "name" in qs:
            print("My name is chatbot, and I am a language model trained by Zayan Arshad.")
            text = "My name is chatbot, and I am a language model trained by Zayan Arshad."
        elif "should" and "you" and "what" and "call" in qs:
            print("My name is chatbot, and I am a language model trained by Zayan Arshad.")
            text = "My name is chatbot, and I am a language model trained by Zayan Arshad."
        elif ("hello" in qs or "hi" in qs) or ("good" and "evening") in qs or ("good" and "morning") in qs or ("good" and "afternoon") in qs:
            print("Hello! Is there any way I can help you?")
            text = "Hello! Is there any way I can help you?"
        elif ("weather" in qs or "weather?" in qs) and ("what" in qs or "pls" in qs or "tell" in qs or "what's" in qs or "whats" in qs):
            url = f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={api_key}'
            response = requests.get(url)
            data = response.json()
            conditions = data['weather'][0]['main']
            temperature = data['main']['temp']
            temperature_celsius = temperature - 273.15
            print("The weather condition is " + conditions + " and the temprature is " + str(temperature_celsius) + " in celcius.")
            text = "The weather condition is " + conditions + " and the temprature is " + str(temperature_celsius) + " in celcius."
        elif ("time" in qs or "time?" in qs) and ("what" in qs or "pls" in qs or "tell" in qs or "what's" in qs or "whats" in qs):
            print("The time is " + str(datetime.now().time()))
            text = "The time is " + str(datetime.now().time())
        elif ("give" in qs or "tell" in qs) and ("joke" in qs or "joke!" in qs):
            response = requests.get("https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Any")
            data = response.json()
            if 'setup' in data:
                setup = data['setup']
                delivery = data['delivery']
                print(setup + "\n" + delivery)
                text = setup + "\n" + delivery
            else:
                joke = data['joke']
                print(joke) 
        elif ("give" in qs or "tell" in qs) and "fact" in qs:
            response = requests.get("https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en")
            data = response.json()
            fact = data['text']
            print("Your random fact is:\n" + fact)
            text = "Your random fact is:\n" + fact
        elif ("8" in qs or "eight" in qs) and ("ball" in qs or "ball," in qs):
            ans_num = r(1, 5)
            ans = ait_ball_ans[ans_num]
            print(ans)
            text = ans
        else:
            print("I'm sorry, but I am not advanced enough to answer your question or statement, a child has made me and my creator is a beginner to python and he has somehow made me. Feel free to ask me anything else or tell me something.")
            text = "I'm sorry, but I am not advanced enough to answer your question or statement, a child has made me and my creator is a beginner to python and he has somehow made me. Feel free to ask me anything else or tell me something."  
        return text

class settings(QWidget):
    global stngs
    def __init__(self):
        super(settings, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("SettingsUI.ui", self)
        self.show()
        self.whitecheckbox.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.blackcheckbox.stateChanged.connect(self.check)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.gotomain)

    def gotomain(self):
        global stngs
        global mn
        stngs = 0
        mn = 1
        self.close()

    def check(self):
        if self.whitecheckbox.isChecked():
            self.white
            
        if self.blackcheckbox.isChecked():
            self.black
            
    def black(self):
        global black
        global white
        black = 1
        white = 0
        self.whitecheckbox.setChecked(False)

    def white(self):
        global white
        global black
        white = 1
        black = 0
        self.blackcheckbox.setChecked(False)

        
def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MyGUI()
    app.exec_()

    if stngs == 1:
        settingsfunc()

def settingsfunc():
    time.sleep(1)
    app = QApplication([])
    settingswindow = settings()
    app.exec_()

    if mn == 1:
        main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think the reason why this is occurring is because of the code not detecting the state of the checkboxes for the background colour changing options (there is a checkbox for black and one for white) but I do not know why. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that in `check()` you're *not* calling `self.white` nor `self.black`, as they are missing the parentheses. Unfortunately, you also have several other important issues: 1. you should not use globals; 2. only *one* QApplication should always exist; 3. after fixing the calls to `self.white()` and `self.black()`, you'll get partial recursion: if white is checked and you check black, it will call `self.check()` again, causing `self.white()` to be called again; you should use radio buttons along with [QButtonGroup](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) and connect to its signals.

Comment: @musicmante, why shouldnt I use broadcasts? Please tell me what I should do instead. Also, what is the reason that I need to use QButton Group?

Comment: If by "broadcasts" you meant *globals*, and you're using a translator, then please be more careful, as technical terms are *extremely* important and automatic translators are not usually able to tell the difference. There are lots of reason for which they shouldn't be used (or should only be used with extreme awareness), I suggest you to do some research on the subject (try with "why globals are bad"); possible alternatives: instance attributes, function arguments and return values, the Qt signal/slot mechanism. Using QButtonGroup simplifies *grouping* of buttons that are part of the same ->

Comment: -> context, and at the same time allow proper management of multiple toggle buttons such as QCheckBox (and, in this case, QRadioButton is a better choice), avoiding issues like yours, where setting the state of *another* button will cause partial (or even infinite) recursion. Sorry but I cannot explain you more about these topics, as it would be off topic for this post, so I strongly urge you to take your time, carefully **study** the documentation and look for tutorials (starting from [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Tutorials), and avoiding videos, as they are too often badly done).

Comment: @musicmante, yes sorry, I meant to say globals, and also, when I use QRadioButton, it already deactivates the other radio button when I click one. Thank you for helping.